# Error during source generation: "is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for"

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have jenkins build machine with sources mounted on SSD drive. During compilation and source generation I'm getting following error:

> [ERROR]
>   file:/mnt/raid0/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIS_Constructor/vis-web/src/main/webapp/concentrator/binding.xml[13,53]
>   com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId:
>   file:/mnt/raid0/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIS_Constructor/vis-web/src/main/webapp/concentrator/binding.xml;
>   lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 53;
>   "file:/mnt/raid0/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIS_Constructor/vis-web/src/main/webapp/concentrator/concentratorSub.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for
>   "file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIS_Constructor/vis-web/src/main/webapp/concentrator/concentratorSub.xsd"?

binding.xml and xsd file are in the same directory.

Here is the piece of binding.xml

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="concentratorSub.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.ats.vis.services.concentrator" />
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I'm running out of ideas how to fix this.

Any help will be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: Above error happens when `<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="concentratorSub.xsd">` wrong... try using `<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="./concentratorSub.xsd">`

Comment: What happens if you instead use the absolute path it suggests (after *Is this a mistake for...*)?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Nem - How did you resolve this?